# Permissions issue on CentOS 7 in Laravel 5.5 on storage folder

Tags: laravel-5, permissions, centos7

Thanks in advance for the helpers. I am configuring a centOS 7 VPS. I put my laravel 5.5 site there. I got the permissions issue with laravel log file. I changed the permissions to 777 recursively. But the issue still remains.

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error that you get ??

Comment: @maraboc 

The stream or file "/var/www/html/notesApp/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: OK run those commands in the server terminal :
`cd app/` `chown -R storage` `cd storage/` `find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` !!

Comment: @maraboc chown -R storage this command gives error "missing operand after 'storage' "

Comment: OK skip that command and test the others :p

Comment: and now missing argument to '-exec' error appears

Comment: There is no syntax error split the command to this `find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` and then this `find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155896/discussion-between-qasim-ali-and-maraboc).

Answer (score 0):

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/laravel chmod -R 755
>   /var/www/html/laravel/storage